# Getting error "System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate." while installing openstack/snap service

Tags: 20.04

```
prashant@BGRGP93:~$ microstack
microstack: command not found
```

Try to install with below commands

```
prashant@BGRGP93:~$ sudo snap install microstack --beta --devmode
[sudo] password for prashant:
error: cannot communicate with server: Post http://localhost/v2/snaps/microstack: dial unix /run/snapd.socket: connect: no such file or directory
```

checked online for how to fix the above error... they suggested to try below steps... but I get error while starting snapd.service

```
prashant@BGRGP93:~$ sudo systemctl unmask snapd.service
prashant@BGRGP93:~$ sudo systemctl enable snapd.service
prashant@BGRGP93:~$ sudo systemctl start snapd.service
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
```

version of my system

```
prashant@BGRGP93:~$ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=focal
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS"
prashant@BGRGP93:~$
```

I get this error lot of times while installing openstack... I am using wsl2 on windows 10 ...

The same snap install works on gcp instance correctly with ubuntu 16.04

Comment: yes.. its wsl 2 system on windows 10...

Comment: It's telling you that build of Openstack is not designed to be compatible with WSL. Too many Linux services don't exist in a WSL system. Try a different approach (like a VM).

Comment: `systemctl` is not compatible with WSL2. use `service` instead. Read the detailed answer here - https://askubuntu.com/a/1379567/395322