# System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate

Tags: boot, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I use WSL2 on Windows 11. I want to run the `systemctl` command in Ubuntu 20.04, but it gives me the following error:

```
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). 
Can't operate. Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: The `systemctl` command won't work on WSL without some serious hacking. Not recommended.

Comment: Why would you want to use `systemctl` on Windows 11? You should be using Windows commands. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to restart ssh service in Ubuntu 20.04 which runs using WSL2

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix The OP is running Ubuntu in WSL2. The question is not about running systemctl in Windows but in Ubuntu. That said user535733 is absolutely right.

Comment: Okay, thank you!

Comment: Try using the `service` command instead.

Comment: Specifically, `sudo service ssh restart`.  But be aware that `ssh` doesn't quite work as you might expect under WSL2 either.

Comment: Thank you, all!

Comment: "Why"? He was likely following an install guide. Eg, https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-redis-on-ubuntu-20-04

Answer (score 250, accepted):

Surprisingly, after 6 years or so of WSL, there doesn't seem to be a good, general-purpose "Systemd" question here on Ask Ubuntu.  So this looks like a good one to use for that purpose.

In general, when you see *either* of the following two messages:

- `System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.`
- `Failed to connect to bus: Host is down`

Then it's typically the same root cause.  In the case of `systemctl` and attempting to start `ssh`, you are seeing both.

The problem may be that:

- Your release of WSL doesn't support Systemd.  In this case, there are multiple workarounds available.  See the *Alternatives to Systemd in WSL* section below.
- The good news is that Systemd is now officially supported in Ubuntu on many WSL systems.  See below for how to determine if your system supports it and how to enable it (if you need it).

##### Should you enable Systemd in WSL?

First, consider whether you *should* enable Systemd in WSL.  Enabling Systemd will automatically start a lot of background services and tasks that you really may not need under WSL.  As a result, it will also increase WSL startup times, although the impact will be dependent on your system.  Check the *Alternatives* section below to see if there may be a better option that fits your needs.  For example, the `service` command may do what you need without any additional effort.

While I'm happy that Systemd is available as an option, I personally plan on continuing to run without it whenever possible.

##### How to enable Systemd in Ubuntu/WSL

As background, there are now two different "delivery mechanisms" (I'll think of a better term, hopefully) for WSL2.  I'd call them different "versions" or "releases", but we tend to already use that term for WSL version 1 and 2.

- Originally, WSL1 and WSL2 both came as a Windows *feature*, which was enabled through the *Turn Windows features on or off* settings.  This feature was (and still is) built-in to Windows, and is called the "in-box" version of WSL.
- In October of 2021, Microsoft started making WSL2 available as a Windows *application*, which could be installed through the Microsoft Store (and other methods described below).

It's the WSL *application* that supports Systemd.  Currently, the in-box version of WSL does not support Systemd.  To use the new WSL application, you must be on a supported Windows release:

- New WSL users with Windows 11 22H2 or later will automatically receive the application version of WSL when running `wsl --install`, unless specifically adding the `--inbox` option.
- Windows 11 21H2 users can still install the WSL application using the methods below.
- Windows 10 users will need [KB5020030](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/topic/november-15-2022-kb5020030-os-builds-19042-2311-19043-2311-19044-2311-and-19045-2311-preview-237a9048-f853-4e29-a3a2-62efdbea95e2) or later.  Note that it is not yet clear at the time of this update whether older Windows 10 releases will work.  I have personally only been able to validate it on Windows 10 22H2 so far.

With the prerequisite Windows version in place, you can then install or upgrade to the 1.0.0 release (or later) of the WSL application using several methods:

- Through the Microsoft Store (as "Windows Subsystem for Linux").
- Or from the [Releases](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/releases) page in the Github repo.  To install a release manually:

  1. Reboot (to make sure that WSL is not in use at all).  A simple `wsl --shutdown` *may* work, but often will not.
  2. Download the 1.0.0 (or later) release from the link above.
  3. Start an Administrator PowerShell and:

     ```
     Add-AppxPackage <path.to>/Microsoft.WSL_1.0.0.0_x64_ARM64.msixbundle
     wsl --version # to confirm
     ```

Some people may need to run wsl update:

```
wsl --update
```

To enable, start your Ubuntu (or other Systemd) distribution under WSL (typically just `wsl ~` will work).

```
sudo -e /etc/wsl.conf
```

Add the following:

```
[boot]
systemd=true
```

Exit Ubuntu and again:

```
wsl --shutdown
```

Then restart Ubuntu.

```
sudo systemctl status
```

... should show your Systemd services.

---

#### Alternatives to Systemd in WSL

`systemctl` is most often used to start services under Ubuntu.  For older releases that don't support Systemd (or if you just choose not to enable it), there are still several alternatives that might work in place of the `systemctl` command.

Fortunately, Ubuntu is pretty good overall about being able to cope without Systemd.

##### How to handle the lack of Systemd

Systemd at its core is just a (probably gross-oversimplification) "way of accomplishing system tasks".  There is usually (but not always, see footnote below) a way of doing the same task without Systemd, and often more than one way.

- ***Option 1:  "The old way"***

  In Ubuntu on WSL, many of the common system services still have the "old" `init.d` scripts available to be used in place of `systemctl` with Systemd units.  You can see these by using  `ls /etc/init.d/`.

  So, for example, you can start `ssh` with `sudo service ssh start`, and it will run the `/etc/init.d/ssh` script with the `start` argument.

  Even some non-default packages such as MySql/MariaDB will install both the Systemd unit files *and* the old `init.d` scripts, so you can still use the `service` command for them as well.

  To autostart services (a la `systemctl enable`) at startup, see [this answer on Super User](https://superuser.com/a/1685207/1210833) for how to do this with `/etc/wsl.conf`.
- ***Option 2: Docker***

  Many packages/services are available as Docker images.  Docker runs great under Ubuntu on WSL2 (specifically WSL2; it will not run on WSL1).  If there's not a SysVinit "service" script for the service you are trying to start, there may very well be a Docker image available that runs in a containerized environment.

  Example:  Elasticsearch, as in [this question and my answer](https://askubuntu.com/q/1427872/1165986).

  - Bonus #1:  Doesn't interfere with other packages already installed (no dependency issues).
  - Bonus #2:  The Docker images themselves pretty much never use Systemd, so you can often inspect the `Dockerfile` to see how the service is started without Systemd.  For more information see the next option - "The manual way."
- ***Option 3:  "The 'manual' way"***

  <sub>*Edit: Bumped down notch from its former position as "Option 2", since Docker is probably a better alternative for many services.*</sub>

  But some services don't have a init-script equivalent, especially on other distributions.  For simplicity, let's assume that the `ssh` `init.d` script *wasn't* available.

  In this case, the "answer" is to figure out what the Systemd unit files are doing and attempt to replicate that manually.  This can vary widely in complexity.  But I'd start with looking at the Systemd unit file that you are trying to run:

  ```
  less /lib/systemd/system/ssh.service
  ```

  ```
  # Trimmed
  [Service]
  EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/ssh
  ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/sshd -t
  ExecStart=/usr/sbin/sshd -D $SSHD_OPTS
  RuntimeDirectory=sshd
  RuntimeDirectoryMode=0755
  ```

  I've trimmed out some of the less relevant lines for understanding its behavior, but you can `man systemd.exec`, `man systemd.service`, and others to see what most of the options do.

  In this case, when you `sudo systemctl start ssh`, it:

  - Reads environment variables (the `$SSHD_OPTS`) from `/etc/default/ssh`
  - Tests the config, exits if there is a failure
  - Makes sure the RuntimeDirectory exists with the specified permissions.  This translates to `/run/sshd` (from `man systemd.exec`).  This also removes the runtime directory when you stop the service.
  - Runs `/usr/sbin/sshd` with options

  So, if you don't have any environment-based config, you could just set up a script to:

  - Make sure the runtime directory exists.  Note that, since it is in `/run`, which is a `tmpfs` mount, it will be deleted after every restart of the WSL instance.
  - Set the permissions to `0755`
  - Start `/usr/sbin/sshd` as root

  ... And you would have done the same thing *manually* without Systemd.

  Again, this is probably the simplest example.  You might have much more to work through for more complex tasks.
- ***Option 4:  Run Systemd as PID 1 in a PID namespace/container***

  Finally, it's *possible* to get Systemd running under WSL2 (but not WSL1).  This is a fairly advanced topic, although there are multiple scripts and projects that attempt to simplify it.

  ***Warnings:** Systemd fundamentally changes many aspects of Ubuntu when started, including the way that X sockets, login, WSL Interop, temp files, and more!  Due to the shared VM nature of WSL2, some of these changes can even impact other distributions you are using *without* Systemd.*

  *My personal recommendation is to either (a) make sure that you understand what is going on behind the scenes should you use one of these techniques, (b) don't do it!, or (c) at the very least, when asking questions about why something doesn't work, make sure to let people know that you are using a Systemd helper script under WSL (and which one).*

  With that out of the way ...

  Let's start with some of the more popular projects to enable Systemd in WSL:

  - [Genie](https://github.com/arkane-systems/genie)
  - [WSL2-Hacks](https://github.com/shayne/wsl2-hacks)
  - [Distrod](https://github.com/nullpo-head/wsl-distrod)

  I don't personally run any of them on a regular basis, but all are open-source, and I've scanned the source to compare the techniques.  At the core, each creates a new namespace or container where Systemd can run as PID 1.

  You can see this in action by following the steps:

  1. Run:

     ```
     sudo -b unshare --pid --fork --mount-proc /lib/systemd/systemd --system-unit=basic.target
     ```

     This starts Systemd in a new namespace with its own PID mapping.  Inside that namespace, Systemd will be PID1 (as it must, to function) and own all other processes.  However, the "real" PID mapping still exists outside that namespace.

     Note that this is a "bare minimum" command-line for starting Systemd.  It will not have support for, at least:

     - Windows Interop (the ability to run Windows `.exe`)
     - The Windows PATH (which isn't necessary without Windows Interop anyway)

     The scripts and projects listed above do extra work to get these things working as well.
  2. Wait a few seconds for Systemd to start up, then:

     ```
     sudo -E nsenter --all -t $(pgrep -xo systemd) runuser -P -l $USER -c "exec $SHELL"
     ```

     This enters the namespace, and you can now use `ps -efH` to see that `systemd` is running as PID 1 in that namespace.

     At this point, you should be able to run `systemctl`.
  3. And after proving to yourself that it's possible, I recommend exiting all WSL instances completely, then doing `wsl --shutdown`.  Otherwise, you will have some things be "broken" until you do.  They can likely be "fixed", but that's beyond the scope of any one Ask Ubuntu question ;-).  My recommendation is to refer to the projects above to see how they handle it.

###### Footnote 1 - Snap

There are certain applications and function in Ubuntu that are just so complex that they are unlikely to ever be disentangled from Systemd.  The most obvious example here would be the Snap system.  I'm sure it's *theoretically possible* that a version of the Snap system could be created without the use of Systemd.  However, there are two good reasons why this won't happen (anytime soon, at least):

- Snap is a system created and supported by Canonical.
- Canonical *has* selected Systemd as the Ubuntu init system.  Just because WSL doesn't support it (easily) doesn't change this.  Canonical developers wrote the Snap system with the expectation that the functionality of Systemd is present.
- There currently doesn't seem to be any third-party desire to port Snap to non-Systemd distributions.  Those distributions typically utilize Flatpak in place of Snap.  It should be noted, however, that even Flatpak tends to utilize Systemd on distributions where it is available.  However, Flatpak is also available for non-Systemd distros.

###### Footnote 2 - Gnome

Gnome is also an application (ecosystem) that is very tightly coupled with Systemd, but it's popular enough that there *have* been ports to non-Systemd init systems.  That said, running it on Ubuntu does assume the presence of Systemd, so you would have to reverse-engineer the process used on those other distributions if you wanted to run it on Ubuntu/WSL without the use of Systemd.

###### Footnote 3 - Other Systemd-dependent applications

There are also cases where certain software *expects* Systemd and just won't work (or at least not fully) if it isn't present.  One that I came across recently is [Cockpit](https://cockpit-project.org).

While I was able to get it up and running without Systemd, it ultimately expects Systemd to be present in order to execute many, if not most, functions.  In effect, parts of Cockpit are a front-end to Systemd.

This type of software, one that *executes* Systemd commands (such as `systemctl`), may be the exception to the "there's an alternative" rule.

Comment: A good question, and **a good answer**, so plus one. I thought that `service` cmd belongs to `systemd`. I have on wsl the error from the OP, but `mariadb` works with `service`.[service](https://askubuntu.com/a/903405/321926)  is a `wrapper` and can be used with `init.d` and `systemctl`.

Comment: I'm confused. WSL used to have systemctl/d, WSL used to work fine with mounted drives, WSL used to be a very solid representation of Ubuntu... now I'd call it Winbuntu as it seems its no longer ubuntu but windows version of it corrupted to fit in WSL... which is strange, because I remember when WSL 1 came out I was able to install TRUE ubuntu on it without issue through powershell instead of the windows store. What happened to WSL? Is there any way to get true ubuntu back?

Comment: @gunslingor I agree ... you're confused ;-).  But seriously, you are almost certainly remembering this incorrectly (or perhaps nostalgically).  WSL has never had Systemd support.  [Here's the Github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/994) on the topic, opened just 15 days after the first WSL1 beta was made available.

Comment: A related comment in that issue, *"running WSL without cron or syslog or sshd or a terminal emulator (what we have got is sort of a console emulator) and other servers/daemons/background tasks, is not the same as running an Ubuntu developer machine"*, shows that people didn't considered it "real Ubuntu" even back then.  WSL has made great progress over the years since then, but it's still a *developer tool* on Windows, not a virtual machine designed to replicate a "full Ubuntu (or other Linux) environment."

Comment: Yeah, hyperV is probably what i was remembering, pure ubuntu image. I suspect WSL is using some component of that pretweaked and routed to the host system to serve itself easier... or lxssmanager or something, i forget. Docker seems to run better in wsl ubuntu than as docker destop using wsl and then you also have very slow ubuntu when using a mounted windows share, but fast ubuntu and win when using a mounted ubuntu share... why I suspect its hyperV really... I remember this issue.

Comment: @gunslingor Right- Hyper-V would make sense, as that's really a "pure VM" in that case.  Side note - LxssManager is really just the service behind WSL.

Comment: For option 3, there is a script for it, and it works for me: http://wiki.webperfect.ch/index.php?title=WSL:_System_has_not_been_booted_with_systemd_as_init_system_(PID_1)#:~:text=Failed%20to%20connect%20to%20bus%3A%20Host%20is%20down,is%20not%20enabled%20by%20default%20in%20WSL%202.  also apply the fix: https://github.com/DamionGans/ubuntu-wsl2-systemd-script/issues/36

Comment: @LingYanMeng There are quite a few scripts, and some are more robust than others.  With *all* of them, I recommend understanding *how* they work, because none of them will work in all cases and eventually require some troubleshooting.

Comment: How do I know whether I have the inbox version or not? `wsl --version` prints: `Invalid command line option: --version`.

Comment: @QuolonelQuestions Great question - The results there indicate the In-box version.  If you had the Store version, it would return the actual version (and some additional info).

Comment: You (really good) answer not cover another way to launch services at startup with the `/etc/wsl.conf` file. You can add this kind of directive : 

    [boot]
    command="service apache2 start; service mariadb start"

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config#boot-settings)

Comment: @ArthurLacoste Good point - I focused on *starting* services in this answer, but not how to *autostart* services as boot.  I've added a link to another answer that covers that per your recommendation.  Thanks!

Answer (score 20):

I had a similar issue. I wanted to start Nginx with `sudo systemctl start nginx`, but it didn't work on Ubuntu WSL. I figured out that the `sudo service nginx start` command does exactly the same thing. It can start Nginx without calling `systemctl`.

Comment: Right - I cover using the `service` command to do this in my existing answer.  Please see the section titled, *"The old way"*.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds
You're right. I'm sorry. I missed that point.

Comment: It works, sudo service docker start

Answer (score -1):

The **`systemctl`** is now available in wsl

Add these lines to the `/etc/wsl.conf`
note you will need to run your editor with sudo privileges, e.g: `sudo nano /etc/wsl.conf`

```
[boot]
systemd=true
```

And close out of the nano editor using **CTRL+O** to save and **CTRL+X** to exit.

With the above steps done, close your WSL distro Windows and run **wsl.exe --shutdown** from PowerShell to restart your WSL instances. Upon launch you should have systemd running. You can check this with the command **systemctl list-unit-files --type=service** which should show your services’ status.

Comment: Just a heads-up that I covered this in the [accepted answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1379567/1165986) almost 18 months ago.  We ask that answers here provide new information that isn't available in existing answers.  Thanks!