# landscape-sysinfo.cache: Permission denied when I start Ubuntu 22.04 in WSL

Tags: permissions, 22.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux, motd

I installed Ubuntu 22.04 on Windows 11 using WSL.  I then moved it on another disk with the WSL commands (`--export`/`--import`).

After moving it, the default user was root, so I added the below lines in `/etc/wsl.conf`:

```
[user]
default=numa
```

Now in the message which is shown once a day when I start Ubuntu (MOTD I think), I can see this message:

```
[/etc/update-motd.d/50-landscape-sysinfo: 17: cannot create /var/lib/landscape/landscape-sysinfo.cache: Permission denied]
```

Although it seems to be no harm, I wonder how can I avoid this.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

*Short answer:*

Two options:

- Recommended:

  ```
  sudo apt remove landscape-common
  sudo apt autoremove # Optionally, but recommended so that you can 
  confirm the problem is gone after restarting
  rm ~/.motd_shown
  ```

  Exit and restart Ubuntu/WSL, and the error should no longer appear.
- Or, if you enable Systemd per [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1379567/1165986), the error shouldn't appear either.  However, I don't recommend enabling Systemd just to suppress this error message.  That's a lot of overhead if you don't need it for other purposes.

*More detail*:

Don't worry - This isn't related to you moving the distribution.  The problem is there in *all* 22.04 installations on WSL.  Funny I never noticed it until you pointed it out -- That shows just how much attention I pay to the MOTD :-/.

This is reported at the bottom of [this Github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5242), but it's not related to  *that* particular issue (which was previously, and continues to be, fixed).

The problem here is that the Ubuntu distribution for WSL is based on Ubuntu Server, which includes support for [Landscape](https://landscape.canonical.com), a feature for managing servers.

This really isn't applicable to WSL, of course, and probably (I'm guessing here, but I'll try to confirm later) requires Systemd support anyway, which [WSL does not have](https://askubuntu.com/a/1379567/1165986).  I have a feeling that there's a Systemd unit that sets up the Landscape directory that isn't getting run on WSL; hence the error.

It's safe to remove this package with the above command, and the error will no longer appear.

Comment: As of September [`systemd`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/systemd-support-is-now-available-in-wsl/) is available in WSL

Comment: @Henke Right - All good points.  While I probably could have gone into more detail on why I recommended removing the `~/.motd_shown`, it's really so that it's easy to confirm that the problem is really resolved when you exit and restart.  Otherwise, the MOTD might not be shown again until the next day.  I suggest leaving it in place (but it's fine to remove it entirely), just *temporarily* delete it to make sure it triggers again for confirmation.

Comment: There's no need to restart the entire computer.  You can restart the WSL subsystem alone by running `wsl --shutdown` on the Windows side to shutdown the entire WSL subsystem and kill all WSL processes, then start a new WSL shell.  (Remove `~/.motd_shown` first if you want to test the MOTD message.)

Comment: @DevenT.Corzine Of course - Agreed that there's no need to restart the whole computer; but I never said to restart the computer itself ;-).  When I say *"exit and restart"* in this case, I just mean exit the *shell* and restart.  There's not even any reason to restart the subsystem itself in this case with `wsl --shutdown`.

Comment: @DevenT.Corzine Updated the answer for clarity :-)

Answer (score 1):

Fixed with:

```
sudo usermod -a -G landscape $USER
```

This command adds your user to the `landscape` group.

Then log out and log back in.

Comment: this did not change a thing for me

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1414536) already does a fine job
of getting rid of the error message.

As a matter of taste, I prefer to run the following commands :

```
sudo apt remove -y landscape-common # Remove the package
sudo apt autoremove -y              # Remove orphaned packages
rm -rf ~/.landscape/                # Clean up, no longer used
mv ~/.motd_shown ~/.hushlogin       # Silence “Message Of The Day”
echo lsb_release -dc >> ~/.bashrc   # Display distro at login
```

Each of these commands should be run only once per Ubuntu
distribution.
I've chosen to permanently disable the
*Message Of The Day (MOTD)*.
Instead, I modify `~/.bashrc` to display a description of the Linux
distro on each login.
<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>
Of course, the last two commands don't really have anything to do
with the question asked.
I just prefer to replace the "MOTD" with something that's more useful
to me.
In addition, I start WSL in the user's home directory, by calling
`wsl ~ -d Ubuntu` rather than changing the directory in `~/.bashrc`.
I attribute [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/q/1414483/#comment2518410_1443293)
for pointing out the `wsl ~` option to me.
Either option is fine – it's just a matter of taste.
However, if you want to use the
[ConEmu context menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWzKQ.jpg),
then you *must not use either of the options*.
If you do, WSL will not start in the *current directory* – the one
from where you call *WSL Bash Here (ConEmu - Admin)*.

Comment: All good, except for that last one.  I really would recommend that users *don't* put the auto-cd into their startup config, as that can cause unintended consequences elsewhere.  Best to let the terminal application handle that by starting `wsl ~`.  I recently came across a comment from one of the WSL developers recommending against the `cd` in `~/.bashrc`, as well, but I forgot to save it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep using landscape, then you can change the `stamp` for the `landscape-sysinfo.cache` location to be stored say in `/tmp`.

```
sudo nano /etc/update-motd.d/50-landscape-sysinfo
```

and make the following changes that starts at like the 4th line:

```
# stamp="/var/lib/landscape/landscape-sysinfo.cache"
stamp="/tmp/landscape-sysinfo.cache"
```

Write Out the file and exit.  It shouldn't give you any more grief until the next update that makes a change to that `50-landscape-sysinfo` file.