# Strange behavior when typing sudo password

Tags: password, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 on Windows 10 WSL. I am trying to get Docker running. But when opening Ubuntu, I cannot log in, and a few of the letters of my password are typed. Where is the problem?

[image: screenshot of issue]

Comment: I don't understand. Are you pressing keys and nothing is happening in the password field?

Comment: I am pressing keys and I don't know exactly what is happening except that I see few casual letters appearing and login failed. I think it has something to do with wsl because this happens when I run "wsl --shutdown" and then start to run wsl again.

Answer (score 1):

WSL normally will never ask for a password when starting up Ubuntu or any other distribution.  From the looks of it, you may have a `sudo <command>` in one of your shell startup files.  Perhaps you are trying to `sudo service start docker` or something similar?

Try going to PowerShell and running `wsl ~ -e bash --noprofile --norc`.  This will start Ubuntu, run Bash as the shell, but tell it not to process the startup files.

I'm assuming that you'll be able to start without it asking for a password, but if not we'll keep troubleshooting that part.

If it does startup without a password, then examine your `~/.bashrc` for a `sudo` command.  Remove it if you find it.  Other candidates includes `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.profile`, but the rc file is the likeliest candidate.

If you are trying to start Docker (since you mention it in the question), there are three better options:

- Docker Desktop is pre-integrated with WSL and will likely alleviate most of your configuration pain.  This is the preferred way to run Docker under WSL.
- Under WSL, you can start services as root without requiring `sudo` by placing them in your `/etc/wsl.conf` as mentioned in [my Super User answer](https://superuser.com/a/1685207/1210833) on the topic.
- You can now start services via Systemd if desired by using the latest WSL version as noted in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1379567/1165986).