# System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate. Failed to connect to bus: Host is down

Tags: boot, 22.04, systemd, services, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have Windows 11 with Ubuntu installed with WSL2. I'm not able to configure Systemd in order to use snap installations.

I have configured the file `/etc/wsl.conf` configured with the following entries (According to [this page](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/systemd-support-is-now-available-in-wsl/)):

```
[boot]
systemd=true
```

But it doesn't work for me.

I can execute `systemctl list-unit-files --type=service` and list the services, but when I try to start, stop or see the status of a service there is the error:

```
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1).
Can't operate. Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
```

`uname -a` lists the following:

```
Linux XXXXXXXXXXXX 5.10.102.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1 SMP Wed Mar 2 00:30:59 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`lsb_release -a` lists the following:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
```

I have also tried to configure according to [this page](https://github.com/DamionGans/ubuntu-wsl2-systemd-script) but my installation always gets broken.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Can you add the output of `wsl --version` to your question (in code-blocks).  Thanks!

Comment: I have already found the issue. Eventhough It was WSL2, was a latter version. I find out that the version that comes with Windows 11 is outdated, and doesn´t update when we run the Windows updates. Also find out that the latest version is the one in Windows Store. I have installed that one and now SYSTEMD works very well, and also could install the the snap packages...

Comment: The version now is the following: 

`wsl --version
Versión de WSL: 1.0.0.0
Versión de kernel: 5.15.74.2
Versión de WSLg: 1.0.47
Versión de MSRDC: 1.2.3575
Versión de Direct3D: 1.606.4
Versión DXCore: 10.0.25131.1002-220531-1700.rs-onecore-base2-hyp
Versión de Windows: 10.0.22000.1219
`
I hope this could help others to have Ubuntu in WSL2 and SYSTEMD working.

Comment: Good to hear -- Yes, that's what I was assuming your issue was.  Marking this as a duplicate of  [System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1379425/system-has-not-been-booted-with-systemd-as-init-system-pid-1-cant-operate).  I do cover in one of my answers there that you have to install the latest WSL version for Systemd to work ;-).  When you see this, if you could mark this as "That solved my problem" in the header so that this gets closed out.  Thanks!