# Systemd in degraded state after enabling in WSL

Tags: 22.04, systemd, windows-subsystem-for-linux

After enabling Systemd per [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1379567/1165986) in Ubuntu 22.04, `sudo systemctl status` shows `State: degraded`.

Additionally:

```
$ sudo systemctl --failed

  UNIT                     LOAD   ACTIVE SUB    DESCRIPTION
● systemd-sysusers.service loaded failed failed Create System Users

LOAD   = Reflects whether the unit definition was properly loaded.
ACTIVE = The high-level unit activation state, i.e. generalization of SUB.
SUB    = The low-level unit activation state, values depend on unit type.
1 loaded units listed.
```

How can I transition from `degraded` to `running`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Update*: [WSL 1.1.0](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/releases/tag/1.1.0), currently a pre-release, is reported to fix this issue.  I have not confirmed yet, but it uses the same bind-mount solution I propose below, so I have every confidence that it will work.

Currently, 1.1.0 can be downloaded and installed manually with `Add-AppxPackage`, but when it exits pre-release status (likely with 1.1.1), it should be auto-installed with `wsl --upgrade`.

---

*Old answer (still useful information for understanding the problem):*

This is due to the current use of a symlink from `/dev/shm` to `/run/shm` in WSL.  There are several related Github issues:

- [[systemd] systemd-sysusers.service fails to start](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/9012)
- [Systemd/Snapd: /dev/shm symlink breaks some snaps with "Private Shared Memory" enabled](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/8996)

Among other things, this will cause any Systemd service that makes use of `LoadCredentials=` to fail.  This impacts several other services on other distributions, but `systemd-sysusers` is the only *default* service under Ubuntu 22.10, at least, to make use of this.

The workaround, as documented in #8996, is to create a new Systemd service that corrects the problem before any other Systemd units make use of that shared memory device.

(Likely) **Important** -- *Please check back here or the above Github issues after upgrading WSL to see if there have been any changes which would warrant the reversal of this action.*

```
sudo -e /etc/systemd/system/fix_wsl2_shm.service
```

Add the following:

```
[Unit]
Description=Fix the /dev/shm symlink to be a mount
DefaultDependencies=no
Before=sysinit.target
ConditionPathExists=/dev/shm
ConditionPathIsSymbolicLink=/dev/shm
ConditionPathIsMountPoint=/run/shm

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/rm /dev/shm
ExecStart=/bin/mount --bind -o X-mount.mkdir /run/shm /dev/shm

[Install]
WantedBy=sysinit.target
```

```
sudo systemctl enable fix_wsl2_shm.service
```

Exit Ubuntu, `wsl --terminate <distro_name>` (or `wsl --shutdown`), and restart.

Confirm that `sudo systemctl status` now shows `running`.  If not:

- Confirm whether `sudo systemctl status fix_wsl2_shm.service` shows that the service was loaded.
- Confirm whether `findmnt /dev/shm` shows that it is mounted, or if `ls -ld /dev/shm` shows that it is a symlink.