# Firefox won't run on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: command-line, firefox, icons

When I click on the Firefox icon it seems to work because the little wheel appears and revolves. However, it soon disappears then nothing else happens. When I go into the terminal and ask which firefox the result is /snap/bin/firefox but when I use this path in terminal it doesn't work. I cannot find firefox in anything called 'bin' it is in the snap folder.

Comment: Please add the output of `snap list --all` to the question.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1444967/289138 - has worked very well for along time, getting updates still.

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** Try running `firefox` from command line and observing any error messages. If there are any, please edit your question to include the output.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem. Here is 'snap list --all' and results of running firefox on the command line. Note: when launching from the command line, firefox runs in spite of the warnings. (Adding the info here since I'm unable to comment.)

```
~$ snap list --all
Name                            Version             Rev    Tracking       Publisher   Notes
bare                            1.0                 5      latest/stable  canonical✓  base
core18                          20230503            2751   latest/stable  canonical✓  base,disabled
core18                          20230530            2785   latest/stable  canonical✓  base
core20                          20230404            1879   latest/stable  canonical✓  base,disabled
core20                          20230503            1891   latest/stable  canonical✓  base
core22                          20230531            750    latest/stable  canonical✓  base
firefox                         114.0.1-1           2760   latest/stable  mozilla✓    -
firefox                         114.0-3             2748   latest/stable  mozilla✓    disabled
gnome-3-38-2004                 0+git.6f39565       137    latest/stable  canonical✓  disabled
gnome-3-38-2004                 0+git.6f39565       140    latest/stable  canonical✓  -
gnome-42-2204                   0+git.ff35a85       111    latest/stable  canonical✓  -
gnome-42-2204                   0+git.587e965       105    latest/stable  canonical✓  disabled
gtk-common-themes               0.1-81-g442e511     1535   latest/stable  canonical✓  -
gtk-common-themes               0.1-79-ga83e90c     1534   latest/stable  canonical✓  disabled
hunspell-dictionaries-1-7-2004  1.7-20.04+pkg-6fd6  2      latest/stable  brlin       -
musescore                       3.6.2               216    latest/stable  musescore✓  disabled
musescore                       3.6.2               228    latest/stable  musescore✓  -
snapd                           2.59.2              19122  latest/stable  canonical✓  snapd,disabled
snapd                           2.59.4              19361  latest/stable  canonical✓  snapd



~$ firefox

(firefox:2923946): Gtk-WARNING **: 05:43:19.840: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:1:21: Failed to import: Error opening file /home/lee/snap/firefox/2760/.config/gtk-3.0/colors.css: No such file or directory
Gtk-Message: 05:43:19.858: Failed to load module "colorreload-gtk-module"
ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.
ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.
amdgpu: os_same_file_description couldn't determine if two DRM fds reference the same file description.
If they do, bad things may happen!
ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.

(firefox:2923946): dconf-WARNING **: 05:43:20.362: unable to open file '/etc/dconf/db/site': Failed to open file “/etc/dconf/db/site”: open() failed: No such file or directory; expect degraded performance
```

Comment: Hi and welcome! You seem to be putting a supporting comment in an answer. Please only put solutions to questions in the answer section and comments as comments, thanks. If you need to show to logs etc. please use a site like pastebin.