How to lower priority or block installation of all Snap packages through APT?
I am trying to prevent APT from installing any Snap-based packages on my system. For example, some packages are offered as Snap versions with names like the following:

Firefox: 1:1snap1-0ubuntu5
Thunderbird: 2:1snap1-0ubuntu3
Chromium-browser: 2:1snap1-0ubuntu2

I want to block or lower the priority of all such Snap versions so that APT defaults to .deb packages from other repositories or PPAs. However, the method I tried so far hasn't worked.
I created a snap.pref file in /etc/apt/preferences.d/ folder with the following content:
Package: *
Pin: version *snap*
Pin-Priority: -1

However, apt responded with W: Did not understand pin type version and didn't update the priority for Snap-based packages.
Can you suggest the right way to do this?

should the Pin-Priority: not be 501? see reference

https://askubuntu.com/a/1444967/289138

Uninstall Snap and Snap applications. Install the required applications by downloading the .deb or .tar.gz files, from their original sites.

I'm not asking how to install a specific package. I'm asking how to lower the priority for ALL Snap packages in APT.

Would you rather disable snap packages all together?  See: My not accepted, but correct answer

@eyoung100 I don't want to lose the ability to install Snap packages. I just don't want Snap packages to be imposed on me through APT.

I asked that because the default in 24.04 is to use Snap for every package that is an app.  The pin priority is ignored in this instance, i.e., if the app is available in the Software Store it is a Snap package @kyodake, and I are both correct.  Uninstalling Snap as my answer states forces APT to use a .deb package if it's available.
